# Adding a node to QDomNodeList

Tags: qt, qt4

I have one empty QDomNodeList (list1) and another one (list2) containing direct child nodes of node A as mentioned in above XMl.

```
<A>
    <P></P>
    <P></P>
    <Q>
       <P></P>
    </Q>
</A>
```

Now i want to copy only those nodes from list2 to listq which have name Q.

I am not able to copy nodes from list2 to list1.

```
QDomNodeList list1,list2;
list2 = a.childNodes(); // copying child nodes of a tag in list 2 

for(int i = 0 ; i < list2.count() ; i++)
{
    if(list2.at(i).nodeName() == "Q")
    {
        cout<<"i : "<<i<<endl;
        // Appending is giving error "Calling appendChild() on a null node does nothing"
        list1.at(i).appendChild(list2.at(i));
    }
}
cout<<"No of Q : "<<list1.count()<<endl;
```

How can i do same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Thanks for the advice ( I was not aware of its importance before)

2. here is my code

 QDomNodeList list1,list2;

 list2 = a.childNodes(); // copying child nodes of a tag in list 2

        for(int i = 0 ; i < list2.count() ; i++)
        {
            if(list2.at(i).nodeName() == "Q")
            {
                cout<<"i : "<<i<<endl;

                list1.at(i).appendChild(list2.at(i));
            }
        }

        cout<<"No of Q  :   "<<list1.count()<<endl;

Appending is giving error "Calling appendChild() on a null node does nothing"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list1.at(i)` will return you a default constructed node as your list is empty, so it will be a null node. That's where error comes from.

You need to create temporary `QDomDocument` to store nodes you want.

```
QDomDocument temporary("tempDoc");
QDomNodeList list1,list2;
list2 = a.childNodes();
// copying child nodes of a tag in list 2 
for(int i = 0 ; i < list2.count() ; i++)
{
    if(list2.at(i).nodeName() == "Q")
    {
        cout<<"i : "<<i<<endl;
        temporary.appendChild(temporary.importNode(list2.at(i), true));
    }
}
list1 = temporary.childNodes();
cout<<"No of Q : "<<list1.count()<<endl;
```

Comment: Hi Kamil,

I tried your suggestion.

Still, list1.count() is displaying 0.

Comment: And did you get any "i : " output?

Comment: i output is displaying correct value (even in my code) but the problem is with adding the desired node of list2 to list1.

In above code temporary.childNodes().count() also displays 0.